# Debian 9 won't wake up after suspend

Tags: debian, suspend

Since some weeks ago, my Debian 9 distro is randomly not waking up after suspend. It does not matter the way of suspending: it can be by using the command `systemctl suspend` (a shortcut that I'm using with i3wm) or by closing the lid.

It happens the following: for some seconds I can move the mouse or the keyboard. Then the screen is frozen, and the only thing I can do is to press the shutdown button.

I checked the dmesg and I've read the `/var/log/syslog` file. There were some errors about mysql, vbox and bluetooth. I ended up uninstalling mysql, php, vbox and disabling the bluetooth (I never used it).

I also edited the file `/etc/default/grub` to modify this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"`, I executed the command `sudo update-grub` and the problem persists after rebooting the laptop.

It's a Thinkpad Lenovo T530. I'm not sure if I should update the BIOS, since everything worked fine since the day I installed Debian 9 (year 2018). Using a SSD disk since that moment.

The problem persists and it's really random. Sometimes it wakes up perfect and I can use it several hours. Two times the computer frozes while using it, too.

What should I check?

Comment: `nouveau` can be finicky, try using NVIDIA binary drivers instead: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Comment: It's also possible it's down to a regression in the kernel. I'd recommend installing a newer kernel, i.e. from Debian 10 or backports.

Comment: Yeah, it was about the kernel version. Instead of going to Debian 10, I did a downgrade to the last kernel version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed! Last month I upgraded the kernel to the version 4.9.0.16, so now I did a downgrade to the last kernel version (4.9.0.15).

Steps:

1. Reboot and select the version 4.9.0.15 in the grub menu.
2. Uninstall the version 4.9.0.16 (`sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.9.0-16-common linux-headers-4.9.0-16-amd64`).
3. Reboot normally.