# In my dualboot, KDE Neon(Ubuntu based) does not wake up after sleep/supend/closing lid manually, it needs to be started again manually 9/10 times

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, hibernate, sleep, kde-neon

I think the title covers it all. I have KDE Neon dualboot with Windows 10. 9 out of 10 times, if it gets to sleep mode it does not wake up. I need to press the power button to power on the laptop again. I am at my wits end about this issue.

Edit:
Expected behavior: When the laptop goes to sleep/suspend mode automatically or manually by closing the lid, I will be able to wake it up and continue working.

System info from `sudo lshw -short` -

```
H/W path           Device           Class          Description
==============================================================
                                    system         Latitude 7480 (07A0)
/0                                  bus            0CXWHP
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/45                               memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/45/0                             memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/45/1                             memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/49                               memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/4a                               memory         512KiB L2 cache
/0/4b                               memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/4c                               processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7600U CPU @ 2.80GHz
/0/100                              bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
/0/100/2                            display        HD Graphics 620
/0/100/4                            generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
/0/100/14                           bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
/0/100/14/0        usb1             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1                       input          2.4G Keyboard Mouse
/0/100/14/0/5                       multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
/0/100/14/0/7                       communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/a                       generic        5880
/0/100/14/1        usb2             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                         generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
/0/100/15                           generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
/0/100/15.1                         generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
/0/100/15.2                         generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2
/0/100/16                           communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/1c                           bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
/0/100/1c/0                         generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.2                         bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
/0/100/1c.2/0      wlp2s0           network        Wireless 8265 / 8275
/0/100/1c.4                         bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
/0/100/1d                           bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9
/0/100/1d/0                         storage        NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
/0/100/1d/0/0      /dev/nvme0       storage        PM961 NVMe SAMSUNG 1024GB
/0/100/1d/0/0/1    /dev/nvme0n1     disk           1024GB NVMe namespace
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/1  /dev/nvme0n1p1   volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/2  /dev/nvme0n1p2   volume         15MiB reserved partition
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/3  /dev/nvme0n1p3   volume         317GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/4  /dev/nvme0n1p4   volume         51GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/5  /dev/nvme0n1p5   volume         504MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/6  /dev/nvme0n1p6   volume         53GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/7  /dev/nvme0n1p7   volume         9765MiB Linux swap volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/8  /dev/nvme0n1p8   volume         260GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/9  /dev/nvme0n1p9   volume         1023MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/a  /dev/nvme0n1p10  volume         8091MiB Linux swap volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/b  /dev/nvme0n1p11  volume         100GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1d/0/0/1/c  /dev/nvme0n1p12  volume         151GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1f                           bridge         Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f.2                         memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                         multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                         bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/100/1f.6        enp0s31f6        network        Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
/0/1                                system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                                system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                                generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/4                                input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/5                                system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/6                                system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/7                                system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/8                                system         PnP device PNP0c02
/1                                  power          DELL KG7VF06
```

OS info -

```
:~$ uname -a
Linux my-machine-name 5.4.0-81-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 19:09:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="KDE neon"
VERSION="5.23"
ID=neon
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="KDE neon User - Plasma 25th Anniversary Edition"
VARIANT="User Edition"
VARIANT_ID=user
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://neon.kde.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://neon.kde.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kde.org/"
LOGO=start-here-kde-neon
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Here are some power related settings :
[image]
[image]

I hope the provided information will help you to help me. If not, please let me know. And of course, thank you in advance.

Comment: If you found a solution post it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your `power management`, the battery icon and disable power management with that box unchecked, your computer will not sleep.

Disabling the Suspend session, or create a separate activity.

You can also disable the lid close sleep mode.

disable the Lid Switch in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` 
If you just want to prevent suspending when the lid is closed you can set the following options

```
   HandleLidSwitch=ignore 
   HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore 
   HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
```

Then run systemctl restart `systemd-logind.service` or `reboot`

How to disable automatic lock screen for KDE

1. Launch System Settings from the Application Launcher.
2. Click on Workspace Behaviour on the sidebar.
3. Go to Screen Locking panel from the sidebar.
4. Click on Lock screen automatically checkbox to uncheck and disable the automatic lock screen.

I work with KDE too, and on my machine `Energy Saving` Options, for `On AC Power`, `On Battery` and `On Low Battery` everythink is disabled, so no sleep mode.

The only setting i have active is under `advanced power settings`
If battery under 10% go to standby.

You can try to create different scripts with custom settings for `Energy Saving`, check `Run script` in `On AC Power`, `On Battery` and `On Low Battery` settings.

Check this post too
[Screen doesn't turn on after closing laptop lid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691691/screen-doesnt-turn-on-after-closing-laptop-lid/691874#691874)

**I had the sleep mod problems with kde and cinnamon desktops, with gnome i have no problems on suspend, lid or sleep.
There are still some bugs with the distros, desktops and some laptops, with the lid close, suspend and sleep.**

**Here are some problems too with gdm3, lightdm and sddm, wayland and X11.**

**Take a look at your bios options too.**

**UPDATE:**

Check this posts maybe you find there a solution for your needs

[Ubuntu 18.04 won't wake after screen lock and blank / suspend / sleep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442057/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-after-screen-lock-and-blank-suspend-sleep)

[Debian 9 won't wake up after suspend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666732/debian-9-wont-wake-up-after-suspend)

[Computer won't wake from sleep after suspend [xfce, debian testing]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416722/computer-wont-wake-from-sleep-after-suspend-xfce-debian-testing)

[Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend)

[When my laptop feels asleep, it won't wake up](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=164586)

> A lot of ubuntu-based distro users are experiencing this. Something is obviously wrong with the sleep mode, but no global solutions can be found. Just wait and pray for the 20.04 to solve this problem...

[Why does my computer not turn back on after I suspended it?](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-suspendfail.html.en)

> If this happens every time you suspend your computer, the suspend feature may not work with your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your approach, the laptop stays 'active' always correct? If I understood correctly it is a workaround so the OS does not go to suspend or sleep mode at all. What if I want to take advantage of the sleep or spend mode, especially where battery life is a concern?

Comment: Correct the laptop stays active. The only setting i have active is under the energy save option there is the point 'advanced power settings' where i set if battery under 10% go to stand by modus